# How to get Web API to deploy automatically upon building, like WCF services

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I would like to achieve, with Web API, the following WCF behaviour:

Using Visual Studio 2015 create a brand new WCF Service Application. Build. Right away the sample service is "online" and can be accessed with a browser, Fiddler, etc. I do not need to explicitly run the project in VS for the services to be available to any client.

I'm completely new to Web API, and have not seen any documentation on how to achieve this same seamless deployment.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the project in Visual Studio (which spins up an IIS Express instance), make sure the IIS feature is turned on on your windows installation, and setup a new site, and point it at the directory of your build output.

For a step-by-step see: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/

Comment: Is this essentially what the WCF project does by default?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, I haven't much experience with WCF stuff, I mostly do WebAPI and MVC projects.

Comment: Looks promising so far. Can I still debug the web project (F5) if it's setup this way (i.e. the website is running in two places--IIS Express and IIS Proper)?

Comment: Yeah, if you hit debug like you're used to, it will run in both places. My workflow is: instead of "Start Debugging" I click "Attach to Process" then find the w3wp.exe process for your site. There's a VS add on called ReAttach to help quickly start debugging like this.